# Create new schema in PostgreSQL using DBeaver

Tags: postgresql, database-schema, dbeaver

At the beginning of my current job I had limited access to DB but recently my role is changed to superuser, admin, and owner. My colleague who was the previous DB admin is able to create a schema or change the permissions as there is a permission tab in the properties and he can change permissions by clicking easily. Would you please let me know how I can create schema and change permissions as well?

Why his dbeaver looks different from me? He can easily right click on the schema folder on top of all schemas on the left side column and select create new schema while I do not have that, like the following picture I found on the internet.

[image]
[image]

Comment: What happens when you run [`create schema`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createschema.html) manually? Maybe your database user doesn't have the necessary privileges

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thank you for your answer. I am able to do both creating schema and changing permissions manually but I want to do it by clicking as well. Would you please let me know if there is any queries that colleague can run to give me full access?

Comment: Sorry, no idea. I don't use DbSchema. But I only manage database objects through SQL statements (or scripts) anyway.